# Javascript/Jquery, callback before submit that changes attribute values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a several forms my webpage, they can be in any location or order...

```
<form id="carform" action='/form.php' js-url='http:www.domain.com/formA.php' >
...
</form>

<form id="truckform" action='/form.php' js-url='http:www.domain.com/formB.php' >
...
</form>

<form id="boatform" action='/form.php' js-url='http:www.domain.com/formC.php' >
...
</form>
```

I would like to add a callback that can replace the action attribute value with the js-url value. I am not sure how to reference the relevant form values. Any help appreciated.

This would be easier if I was referencing a specific form id, but in this case, the code needs to reference the submitting form, whichever it is.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    $('form').submit(function() {
      // Change the action attribute to the js-url attribute value if js-url attribute
      return true; // submit the form
    });  
});
```

Doing this is plain Javascript is ok too.

Comment: Use `$(this).find(...)` to reference items within the form.

Comment: Isn't that one of the first things you learned about jQuery event handlers? `$(this)` is the target of the event.

Comment: self taught, and not very good. Just lots of googling must of the time.  so $(this).find('js-url')?

Comment: `find()` is for finding elements inside the form. Attributes are `$(this).attr("js-url")`.

Comment: But you shouldn't create custom attributes like that. Application-defined attributes should begin with `data-`.

Comment: thank you for advice.  Will change to `data-`, how to I assign value... this does not work $(this).attr('action') = $(this).attr('data-js-url')

Comment: Read the documentation instead of guessing. `$(this).attr('action', $(this).attr('data-js-url'))`

Comment: Thank you! Will do!